# Feed Me finds no elements to process

Tags: plugins, plugin-feedme

Feed Me gives me, out of the blue, the error message below. I realized it only because i had "disable missing elements" active and all my entries where disabled. Feed Me was running over months without errors. I also made no changes to the Feed Settings at all.

[image]

Can anyone explain that to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [pull request on github](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/pull/566) for this. You can [see what to do here](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/pull/566/commits/4092aabd49bcdd630fcf2589826eeed254bf06b4) if you want to fix locally until an update is released.

Comment: It works again, thank you!